# Selenium 3 python: add listener for Chrome DevTools network event

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am using [Selenium 3](https://www.selenium.dev/) with python. Currently it is possible to send a [Chrome DevTools](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) command using the [execute_cdp_cmd](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html?highlight=cdp#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_cdp_cmd) binding:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
response = driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.getAllCookies', {})
print(response)
```

Is it possible somehow to add a listener for a [Network Event](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/)? Something like:

```py
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable')
driver.add_listener('Network.dataReceived', my_listener)
```

It should be natively supported in Selenium 4 (currently in alpha), but I would like to know if it is possible to make this work in Selenium 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this in Selenium 3. In Selenium 3 `add_listener` doesn't look like the `addListener` in Java. Seems it only receives `Console.ERROR` `Console.ALL` and `Console.Log` as paramater.

```py
    @asynccontextmanager
    async def add_listener(self, event_type):
        '''
        Listens for certain events that are passed in.

        :Args:
         - event_type: The type of event that we want to look at.

         :Usage:
             ::

                async with driver.add_listener(Console.log) as messages:
                    driver.execute_script("console.log('I like cheese')")
                assert messages["message"] == "I love cheese"

        '''
        assert sys.version_info >= (3, 7)
        global cdp
        from selenium.webdriver.common.bidi.console import Console

        async with self._get_bidi_connection():
            global devtools
            session = cdp.get_session_context('page.enable')
            await session.execute(devtools.page.enable())
            session = cdp.get_session_context('console.enable')
            await session.execute(devtools.console.enable())
            console = {
                "message": None,
                "level": None
            }
            async with session.wait_for(devtools.console.MessageAdded) as messages:
                yield console
            if event_type == Console.ERROR:
                if messages.value.message.level == "error":
                    console["message"] = messages.value.message.text
                    console["level"] = messages.value.message.level
            elif event_type == Console.ALL:
                console["message"] = messages.value.message.text
                console["level"] = messages.value.message.level
```

Also, this seems not to be supported in Selenium 4 so far.